# htk in ubuntu “make all” error “Nothing to be done for `all'.” error

Tags: bash, ubuntu, speech-recognition, hidden-markov-models, htk

Hello folks actually i am trying to install htk on Ubuntu 14.04.3 .
I did same as per [this tutorial](http://aravindev.blogspot.in/2013/08/installing-htk-34-on-ubuntu-64-bit-os.html) and I also followed [this](http://www.voxforge.org/home/dev/acousticmodels/linux/create/htkjulius/tutorial/download) but I am still facing an error when I try to give the "make all" command.

```
exepaul@ubuntu:~/voxforge/bin/htk$ make all
(cd HTKTools && make all) \
      || case "" in *k*) fail=yes;; *) exit 1;; esac;
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/exepaul/voxforge/bin/htk/HTKTools'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/exepaul/voxforge/bin/htk/HTKTools'
(cd HLMTools && make all) \
      || case "" in *k*) fail=yes;; *) exit 1;; esac;
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/exepaul/voxforge/bin/htk/HLMTools'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/exepaul/voxforge/bin/htk/HLMTools'
```

I already installed all 32 libs and I am also modifying line 77 in the make file but still facing error

My make file is

```
# ----------------------------------------------------------- 
#                                                             
#                          ___                                
#                       |_| | |_/   SPEECH                    
#                       | | | | \   RECOGNITION               
#                       =========   SOFTWARE                  
#                                                             
#                                                             
# ----------------------------------------------------------- 
#         Copyright: Cambridge University
#          1995-2006 Engineering Department
#                    http://htk.eng.cam.ac.uk
#                    http://mi.eng.cam.ac.uk
#                 
#   Use of this software is governed by a License Agreement   
#    ** See the file License for the Conditions of Use  **    
#    **     This banner notice must not be removed      **    
#                                                             
# ----------------------------------------------------------- 
# File: Makefile.  Generated from Makefile.in by configure.
# ----------------------------------------------------------- 

SHELL = /bin/sh
srcdir = .
top_srcdir = .

prefix = /home/exepaul/voxforge/bin/htk
exec_prefix = ${prefix}
bindir = ${exec_prefix}/bin
sbindir = ${exec_prefix}/sbin
libexecdir = ${exec_prefix}/libexec
datadir = ${prefix}/share
sysconfdir = ${prefix}/etc
sharedstatedir = ${prefix}/com
localstatedir = ${prefix}/var
libdir = ${exec_prefix}/lib
infodir = ${prefix}/share/info
mandir = ${prefix}/share/man
includedir = ${prefix}/include
oldincludedir = /usr/include

CC = gcc
CPPFLAGS = 
CFLAGS = $(CPPFLAGS) -ansi -D_SVID_SOURCE -DOSS_AUDIO -D'ARCH="i686"' -Wall -Wno-switch -g -O2
LDFLAGS = -L/usr/X11R6/lib 
LIBS = -lm -lX11 
INSTALL = /usr/bin/install -c

DESTDIR =

pkgdatadir = $(datadir)/@PACKAGE@
pkglibdir = $(libdir)/@PACKAGE@
pkgincludedir = $(includedir)/@PACKAGE@

top_builddir = .

ACLOCAL = @ACLOCAL@
AUTOCONF = @AUTOCONF@
AUTOMAKE = @AUTOMAKE@
AUTOHEADER = @AUTOHEADER@

INSTALL = /usr/bin/install -c
INSTALL_PROGRAM = ${INSTALL} $(AM_INSTALL_PROGRAM_FLAGS)
INSTALL_DATA = ${INSTALL} -m 644
INSTALL_SCRIPT = ${INSTALL}
transform = s,x,x,
MAKEINFO = @MAKEINFO@
PACKAGE = @PACKAGE@
VERSION = @VERSION@

HTKLIB  = HTKLib
HLMLIB  = HLMLib
HTKTOOLS = HTKTools
HLMTOOLS = HLMTools
LVREC = HTKLVRec
HTKBOOK = HTKBook
SUBDIRS = $(HTKLIB) $(HLMLIB) $(HTKTOOLS) $(HLMTOOLS) $(LVREC) $(BOOK) 
ACLOCAL_M4 = $(top_srcdir)/aclocal.m4
mkinstalldirs = $(SHELL) $(top_srcdir)/mkinstalldirs
CONFIG_CLEAN_FILES = 
DIST_COMMON =  README ChangeLog Makefile.am \
Makefile.in aclocal.m4 configure configure.ac install-sh missing \
mkinstalldirs


DISTFILES = $(DIST_COMMON) $(SOURCES) $(HEADERS) $(TEXINFOS) $(EXTRA_DIST)

TAR = gtar
GZIP_ENV = --best

.SUFFIXES:

# build rules
all: htktools hlmtools
$(HTKLIB)/HTKLib.a:
    (cd $(HTKLIB) && $(MAKE) HTKLib.a) \
      || case "$(MFLAGS)" in *k*) fail=yes;; *) exit 1;; esac;
htklib: $(HTKLIB)/HTKLib.a
$(HTKLIB)/HTKLiblv.a:
    (cd $(HTKLIB) && $(MAKE) HTKLiblv.a) \
      || case "$(MFLAGS)" in *k*) fail=yes;; *) exit 1;; esac;
htkliblv: $(HTKLIB)/HTKLiblv.a
$(HLMLIB)/HLMLib.a:
    (cd $(HLMLIB) && $(MAKE) all) \
      || case "$(MFLAGS)" in *k*) fail=yes;; *) exit 1;; esac;
hlmlib: $(HLMLIB)/HLMLib.a
htktools: $(HTKLIB)/HTKLib.a
    (cd $(HTKTOOLS) && $(MAKE) all) \
      || case "$(MFLAGS)" in *k*) fail=yes;; *) exit 1;; esac;
hlmtools: $(HLMLIB)/HLMLib.a
    (cd $(HLMTOOLS) && $(MAKE) all) \
      || case "$(MFLAGS)" in *k*) fail=yes;; *) exit 1;; esac;
hdecode: $(HTKLIB)/HTKLiblv.a
    (cd $(LVREC) && $(MAKE) all) \
      || case "$(MFLAGS)" in *k*) fail=yes;; *) exit 1;; esac;
book: 
    (cd $(HTKBOOK) && $(MAKE) all) \
      || case "$(MFLAGS)" in *k*) fail=yes;; *) exit 1;; esac;

# installation
install-htktools: htktools
    (cd $(HTKTOOLS) && $(MAKE) install) \
    || case "$(MFLAGS)" in *k*) fail=yes;; *) exit 1;; esac;
install-hlmtools: hlmtools
    (cd $(HLMTOOLS) && $(MAKE) install) \
    || case "$(MFLAGS)" in *k*) fail=yes;; *) exit 1;; esac;
install-hdecode:
    (cd $(LVREC) && $(MAKE) install) \
    || case "$(MFLAGS)" in *k*) fail=yes;; *) exit 1;; esac;
install-book: book
    (cd $(HTKBOOK) && $(MAKE) install) \
    || case "$(MFLAGS)" in *k*) fail=yes;; *) exit 1;; esac;

clean:
    /bin/rm -f *~
    @for dir in $(SUBDIRS); do \
      (cd $$dir && $(MAKE) clean) \
      || case "$(MFLAGS)" in *k*) fail=yes;; *) exit 1;; esac; \
    done && test -z "$$fail"
distclean: clean
    /bin/rm -f Makefile config.h config.status config.cache config.log
    @for dir in $(SUBDIRS); do \
      (cd $$dir && $(MAKE) distclean) \
      || case "$(MFLAGS)" in *k*) fail=yes;; *) exit 1;; esac; \
    done && test -z "$$fail"

install: install-htktools install-hlmtools
docs: book

mkinstalldir:                                               
    if [! -d $(bindir) -a X_ = X_yes ] ; then mkdir -p $(bindir) ; fi

.PHONY: all doc install clean distclean htklib-decode \
    htktools hlmtools hdecode docs book \
    install-htktools install-hlmtools install-hdecode install-book



  [1]: http://aravindev.blogspot.in/2013/08/installing-htk-34-on-ubuntu-64-bit-os.html
  [2]: http://www.voxforge.org/home/dev/acousticmodels/linux/create/htkjulius/tutorial/download
```

Please help, I have been trying for 2 days :(

Comment: Did `./configure` complete without any errors?

Comment: Already asked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35479159/htk-in-ubuntu-make-all-error-nothing-to-be-done-for-all

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is make printing "make: Nothing to be done for \`all'."?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32903139/why-is-make-printing-make-nothing-to-be-done-for-all)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a valid `Makefile`.  It looks like a `Makefile.in` or maybe `Makefile.am` which should be further processed by `configure` and/or `automake`, respectively, to produce an actually workable `Makefile`.

Answer (score 0):

I had been having the [same problems with HTK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57597548/htk-compile-error-make1-nothing-to-be-done-for-all/57600102#57600102). Try running `make clean` before `make all`. It might be the wrong Makefile (the right one is `/htk/HLMTools/Makefile`) but from the errors your receiving - which are the same as mine - running `make clean` should do it. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32903139/why-is-make-printing-make-nothing-to-be-done-for-all).